# Redux Sagas Call not calling the function passed to it

Tags: typescript, redux-saga

I've got my sagas working fine and I wanted to adapt some things. The thing is that now my function inside the sagas is not being called.

Here is what I have:

```js
function* createTrip(){
  try{ ... }
  catch(error) {
    // returns an object if needed, this way it only logs into our logger
    createErrorReport(Errors.FailedToCreateTrip, { error });
  }
}
```

The createTrip works and is calling the createErrorReport. But I wanted to do the following:

```js
function* createTrip(){
  try{ ... }
  catch(error) {
    const response = yield* call(createErrorReport, Errors.FailedToCreateTrip, { error })
    // I may need now some info from what is returned
    // the function is not a promise, it returns just an object
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the problem that you are using `yield*` instead of just `yield` ?

Comment: Actually no, it does not any difference. The * is because we are using typescript, so it gives response the correct type

Comment: Is there something when I use the _call_ method inside the catch block?

Comment: Pretty sure that when using `yield*` the expression after needs to be an iterable, typescript or not https://mzl.la/3zD6FFc